# Performance tuning

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a performane problem. My manager said me to tune a select statement.

We are having a table

```
SELECT [AcctDetailReportId]
      ,[WorkOrderEneteredDate]
      ,[LocationName]
      ,[LocationNumber]
      ,[District]
      ,[CostCenter]
      ,[GLCode]
      ,[WorkType]
      ,[RequestType]
      ,[RequestCode]
      ,[ServiceLocation]
      ,[Cause]
      ,[Remedy]
      ,[RequestDescription]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[Priority]
      ,[WorkOrderNumber]
      ,[Status]
      ,[DNE]
      ,[InvoiceNumber]
      ,[VendorCode]
      ,[VendorName]
      ,[Quote1]
      ,[Quote2]
      ,[Invoiceid]
      ,[InvoiceSubmittedDate]
      ,[WorkComplete]
      ,[TotalLaborCost]
      ,[TotalMaterialCost]
      ,[SalesTax]
      ,[InvoiceTotal]
      ,[WarrantyExpirationDate]
      ,[UnderWarranty]
      ,[MallName]
      --,[AddressID]
      --,[CommunicationID]
      --,[ContactID]
      --,[StateID]
      --,[CountryID]
      --,[LanguageID]
      --,[AddressTypeID]
      ,[Line1]
      ,[Line2]
      ,[City]
      ,[Province]
      ,[Region]
      ,[ZipPostalCode]
      --,[DeactivateDateTime]
      --,[DeactivateUser]
      ,[CreateDateTime]
      ,[CreateUser]
      --,[PreviousRecordID]
      ,[LocationState]
      ,[CheckNumber]
      ,[CheckDate]

 FROM [Darden].[dbo].[RPT_AccountDetailReport]
GO"
```

which contains of 29000 records. it takes about 2 mins to retrieve data using Clustered Index Scan..

Table has only one Clustered Index.

Requirement is to get all records in a table and all columns..  But in reduced time..

Can any one help me on that...

Thanks,

Karthik

Comment: I am guessing that `RPT_AccountDetailReport` is a view. Can you show the underlying SQL for that?

Comment: What is your manager going to do with all 29,000 rows?

Comment: RPT_AccountDetailReport is not a view, It is a table... Need to improve performance on "select * from RPT_AccountDetailReport"

Comment: @ Aaron Bertrand.. Thats what my question to him.. I asked him what is the need of retrieving all 29000 rows at a time.. if we can give where condition then Query optimizer will go for Index seek.. it takes around 2 secs.. But he says that he need all records

Comment: @user - it may also help to know your datatypes.  Part of the issue could be that you have some overly-large fields that cause page splits or something.

Comment: I have to ask ... does it take two minutes for ONLY the query to execute (like in Management Studio ON the server), or does it take 2 minutes for an application to execute the query and load something like a .NET GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Have you reorganized/rebuilt your index(s)  the script below will scripts to re/create all the indexes for a table where i.name = '%what ever you put here%'.  There are a bunch of lines below that are remmed out that I have used in the past.

```
SELECT
--stats.object_id AS objectid,
--QUOTENAME(s.name) AS schemaname,
--stats.index_id AS indexid,
i.name AS index_name,
--stats.partition_number AS partitionnum,
stats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS frag,
stats.page_count,
QUOTENAME(o.name) AS objectname,
CASE  
      when stats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent < 30 then 'Reorganize'
      when stats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30 then 'Rebuild'
END AS 'action_to_take',
CASE  
      when stats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent < 30 then 'ALTER INDEX '+i.name+ ' ON ' +DB_NAME()+'.'+QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(o.name)+' REORGANIZE;' 
      when stats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30 then 'ALTER INDEX '+i.name+ ' ON ' +DB_NAME()+'.'+QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(o.name)+' REBUILD;' 
END AS 'Statement'
FROM 
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL , NULL, NULL) as stats,
sys.objects AS o,
sys.schemas AS s,
sys.indexes AS i
WHERE o.object_id = stats.object_id
AND s.schema_id = o.schema_id       
AND i.object_id = stats.object_id
AND i.index_id = stats.index_id
AND i.name is not null and i.name not like '%missing index%'
AND stats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 10.0 
--AND stats.page_count >= 5000
--AND stats.index_id > 0
--and i.name like '%880%'
ORDER BY action_to_take,stats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc,stats.page_count desc
```

Or you can click on Display [estimated] Execution plan & SMS will generate any needed indexes.

HTH,
LarryR....

Comment: Did you read the question?  He is selecting all data from a table without a filter.  Adding or rebuilding non-clustered indexes won't help.

Comment: Yes thats what I am trying to say.. Adding a nonclustered index will not have any affect..

Comment: And one more thing Fragmentation level is 0.14%.. And I have only 1 Clustered index on table.. I think above solution will not help me.. Any suggestion to improve performance...